# Type '[{}, Dispatch<{}>]' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use React Context with Typescript and create global state management for my components.

I have this as my State Provider

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

export interface appState {
    note: object,
    reducer: ({type}:{type: string}) => void;
}

export const StateContext = createContext<appState>({} as appState);

export const StateProvider = (reducer: any, initialState: any, children:any ) => (
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
);

export const getState = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

And in my App component I have this code

```
const initialState = {
    note: {}
  };

  interface actionChangeTheme {
    type: 'changeTheme',
    changeTheme: string
  }

  const reducer = (state: appState, action: actionChangeTheme) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'changeTheme':
        return {
          ...state,
          theme: action
        };

      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  return (
    <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
        ...
      </StateProvider>
    );
```

The problem I'm facing is in State Provider, where I'm assigning value to value=`{useReducer(reducer, initialState)}` I'm getting an error `Type '[{}, Dispatch<{}>]' is missing the following properties from type 'appState': note, reducer  TS2739`

I really need help on how to resolve this error.

[Article](https://medium.com/simply/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-at-10-lines-of-code-baf6be8302c) where this idea with State Provider is from

**EDIT**

If I turn my interface into this

```
export interface appState {
    note?: object,
    // reducer: ({type}:{type: string}) => void;
}
```

I'm getting an error Type `'[{}, Dispatch<{}>]' has no properties in common with type 'appState'.`

So I assume I need to do something with my state interface.